# text box is autofilled with mysql data but not textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new and still learning, but have been able to find the solutions to my previous problems... but this one is difficult for me. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

I have an sql database that successfully fills the text boxes in the form, but there is also a comments textarea that is not filled with the contents of the database.

For the text box, the code is

```
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">First Name:
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"<br>
```

For the textarea it is

```
<td colspan="4" rowspan="1"style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">
<textarea cols="120" name="comments" rows="20" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>"></textarea><br>
</td>
```

I am thinking that the syntax is different from text and textarea.

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value=""` attribute in textarea

```
<textarea cols="120" name="comments" rows="20" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>"></textarea>
```

In textarea echo `variable` between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags

```
<textarea cols="120" name="comments" rows="20"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
```

[Reference Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use value property, just use inner content like this:

```
<textarea cols="120" name="comments" rows="20"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
```

Also you have a missing `/>` close tag on the textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" /><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the missing /> to the code in the $fname code... But I still am having the same problem with the textarea where it is not populating the form with the comments field. I can type into the textarea form field on the form and it saves into the database but is not populated into the form like the other text fields are. I'm still searching for the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Value in textarea is after open tag:

```
<textarea><?php echo 'something'; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: If I use <input type="text" name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" /><br> then I can add to the database but still can't populate the field in the form. If I use <textarea cols="120" name="comments" rows="20"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea> I can't add to the database or populate the field. My goal is to be able to populate the form field and also add to the database with textarea. I'm stll searching and I thank you for your help!